# Security concerns with Mustache html templating

Tags: javascript, html, security, web-applications, mustache

I have a usecase where the contents of the mustache HTML template could potentially come from the application/end-user (i.e. The content of the  script tag in the below code snippet.)

```
<script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
  Hello {{ name }}!
</script>
```

As this could potentially lead to execution of malicious code, I'm doing

1. Allowing only a subset of HTML tags and attributes to be added in
   the template (inside the script tag)
2. Allowing only HTML escaped
   variables i.e. only {{name}} is allowed and not {{{name}}}.

Is there anything further that needs to be considered for security of the application?

Comment: It is an interesting question, but a tough one to answer: there can't be a definitive list of potential security issues because some actual issues will be overlooked, and a simple change in the mustache library or **your application code** could open a whole new set of attack opportunities. Why not opening an issue in the mustache github repository, where authors could consider your question with more consideration?

Comment: no risk, none, zero, zip. the script tag just a hidden tag unless the type is "text/javascript", and mustache.js no longer executes any dynamic code, so it cannot be the problem. now, if you allow onmouseover and other crap input, you will of course have problems, but they have nothing to do with a defunct script tag. use <template> if in doubt...

Comment: Thanks. What would happen post template evaluation for the given data.  Please note that both template content and the data is coming from the application. Regarding onmouseover, I'm only allowing a white-list of HTML elements and attributes, so that isn't a problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's not a "moustache" problem if we follow the philosophy "small, sharp tools". Then before mapping an unsecure data (third party JSON) to template you are to validate the data with other tools.

The simplest approach to start with is to replace string fields, contaning unsecure data.

```
function clearJson(userStringData){

  return JSON.parse(userStringData, function(k,v) { 
        // string values containg something like
        // html tags or js block braces will not pass
        return String(v).match('[<>{}]') ? 'UNSAFE' : v;
  });
}
```

The field of code injection is too wide to have a short answer on your question. You may apply any approach which is advanced enough for your application: define data formats the application expects from user and then in runtime remove incoming suspicious data not matching these formats.

Answer (score 1):

You should perform `user inputs` on the **server**, not "only" on the client. If some "bad code" is going to be executed on the client, it's already too late ;)

Comment: Yes, the sanitization of application input that will become part of template will happen on server.